# How to disable and enable a text field during a reactjs event?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to disable and enable a text field with ReactJS.

The scenario is:

1. The use enter the text and hits enter
2. The text field must be disabled to prevent entering new data
3. The text is sent to the server to save
4. After saving the text box must be enabled again.

The problem is that updating a field twice via `setState` function is impossible during a single event in ReactJS, because it only updates once after finishing the related event. So, how could an input field be updated twice during an event?

I also tried using `this.forceUpdate()` after each `this.setState(...)`, but it didn't work.

```
theEvent(e){
  if(e.key==='Enter'){
    this.setState({newTypePredefinedValue: ''});
    this.setState({readOnly:true})
    this.forceUpdate();

    fetch(..., { ... })
      .then(() => this.componentDidMount() )
      .then(this.setState({readOnly:false}))
      .then(this.forceUpdate());
  }
}
```

I'm looking for a way to disable and enable the needed field during an event.

Comment: Why are you doing forceUpdate ?

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you. You need not to force update the state.
Also, You can't call the componentDidMount method explicitly. It is executed only once and that too implicitly when the component mounts initially.

```
theEvent(e){
            if(e.key==='Enter'){
                this.setState({
                  newTypePredefinedValue: '',
                  readOnly:true,
                  value:e.target.value
                });


                fetch(...,
                {
                    ...
                })
                .then(()=>{
                  this.setState({readOnly:false})
                 })

            }else{
              this.setState({
                value:e.target.value
              })
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks DJ, but I think the main point in senario is missed. I need to use setState twice in an event. In your code, setState is run only once according to the if condition.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that you are using

```
.then(this.setState({readOnly:false}))
```

instead of

```
.then(() => this.setState({readOnly:false}))
```

This causes the second `setState` being called immediately instead of when the response arrives and you handle it.

You shouldn't need to call `forceUpdate` either.

## Sample scenario

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/2pi/pen/JqbyMG)

```
class Element extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      readOnly: false,
      input: '',
    }

    this.handleFetch = this.handleFetch.bind(this);
    this.handleInput = this.handleInput.bind(this);
  }

  handleInput(e) {
    this.setState({
      input: e.target.value
    });
  }

  handleFetch(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    this.setState({
      readOnly: true
    });

    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({
        readOnly: false
      })
    }, 4000);

    /* You should use in your actual code

    fetch(..., { ... })
      .then(res => {
        // Handle response

        this.setState({
          readOnly:false
        })
      });

    */

  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.handleFetch}>Click me!</button>
        <input type="text" disabled={this.state.readOnly} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Your function code rewrote as shown in the sample code.

```
theEvent(e){
  if(e.key === 'Enter') {
    this.setState({
      newTypePredefinedValue: '',
      readOnly:true
    });

    fetch(..., { ... })
      .then(res => {
        // Handle response
        this.setState({
          readOnly:false
        })
      });
  }
}
```

Comment: @SadeqS I've implemented a [simple sample](https://codepen.io/2pi/pen/JqbyMG) with your particular use case. Instead of fetching it does setTimeout to simulate the asynchronous fetching. See if it helps.

Comment: Thanks danpeis for the code. It worked well. The only problem is that enabling the text field doesn't depend on the response from server. For example, if the server got disconnected and the text field was needed to remain disbaled, the text field would be enabled after 4 seconds by this code.

Comment: @SadeqS It is a sample code, you should use in your code `fetch(...).then(res => { /* code in setTimeout */ }` I used in this way just to illustrate it for you.

Comment: Thanks again danpeis. I actually did that. However, this new setState runs after 4 seconds! It's not dependent on fetch! I mean if the fetch took more than 4 seconds to respond the textbox would be enabled sooner or if the fetch was shorter, the textbox would be enabled later.

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding me. Let me write a code block for your actual handling code as the example might be confusing for you.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just create input ref and disable it manually.

Have a look at this code snippet, it may help:

```
const Form = () => {
  const [text, setText] = useState('');
  const inputRef = useRef(null);

  const handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    inputRef.current.disabled = true;

    setTimeout(() => {
      inputRef.current.disabled = false;
    }, 3000);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Form:</h2>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <input ref={inputRef} onChange={e => setText(e.target.value)} value={text} />
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  )
}
```

I'm using hooks here but you can make it work with classes too.

Comment: The same happened when I replaced the two setState()s with the code `this.nwTypName.current.disabled = false(true)`. I mean, when I used ref for disabling for only one time, everything was fince, but when I used it twice in an event, only the last use which was `this.nwTypName.current.disabled` worked. In fact, the same happned as when I used setState. I guess reactjs renders the code after the event is finished and that prevents multiple updates (or rendering) during a single event.